# Probability of a girl given 2 boys

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

I recently had a test on Probability Distributions and got this question wrong. Some help would be appreciated. If I recall correctly, the question was :

In a family of 4 children, the probability of a boy and girl is equal.

Then what is the probability of a girl given there are already 2 boys.

I attempted to use binomial distribution with X ~ Bin(2, 0.5) but this wasn't right; I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: I don't know how these questions are usually posed, but to me, the answer is just 50%.  It doesn't matter how many boys came before.  But I don't know what knowledge is being tested here.

Comment: Have a look at the monty hall problem. You can then apply the same logic to get the correct answer (and yes that might be counterintuitive).

Comment: @SalMangiafico It does matter. You can basically just draw a tree of every possible combination and then remove possibilities given "there are already 2 boys".

Comment: Okay.  I guess I don't understand the question being posed.

Comment: This is, I think, going to depend on what you mean by "already". Do you mean "given that the first 2 kids were boys, what is the probability that one of the next two kids is a girl?" One exactly or one or more? Or only the third child? Or do you mean "given that there are at least two boys in a family, what is the probability that one of the other two is a girl?" Or something else? Once you define the terms, you can do as @LaksanNathan and draw  a tree.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 4 possible answers, dependent on how to interpret this question:

1. If the probability for a girl is determined by the fact that there are 2 boys and 2 girls in this family of 4 children. Then the probability for the 3rd child to be a girl, given the first 2 are boys, is 100%.
2. If the probability for a child being a girl is interpreted as a constant 50%, then the probability for the 3rd child being a girl is 50% no matter the gender of the first 2 children.
3. The same as interpretation 2, but here you want to determine the probability that there is **at least 1** girl in the spot of child 3 and 4. This probability is 1-0.5x0.5 = 0.75!
4. If you interpret the question in a way that you have 2^4=16 possible combinations of the 4 childrens gender and out of these you only look at cases with boys >= 2, then you see that there are only 11 possibilities of which only 1 contains 0 girls.   Pr(≥1∣≥2)= 10/11

Comment: Possibly none of these is the intended interpretation, though.  The question seems to be an effort to test a pupil on conditional probabilities and, as such, reads like (a poorly phrased) request to compute $\Pr(G \ge 1\mid B\ge 2)$ where $B$ has a Binomial$(4,1/2)$ distribution and $G=4-B.$ *That* probability is $10/11.$

Comment: @whuber I think you're correct. The question was phrased poorly and I wasn't able to understand exactly what was wanted from me, but knowing it was conditional probability I should have been able to deduce the question. However, I still don't think this is the correct answer since it was a MCQ and I'm pretty sure there wasn't an option so high

Comment: About the only way to figure out the intended question, then, would be to survey the options that were provided and determine which of them are consistent with some reasonable interpretation.  Right now we're all just guessing.

Comment: I am just ashamed that I forgot the most likely interpretation of all.. Yes, 10/11 is correct in this case! I just calculated it myself.

Comment: I know the question is closed, but maybe for sake of completeness you might want to edit your answer to add that option too.

Comment: @HuyPham: Good idea, I just did!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the samples are independent (i.e. the genders of previous children don't affect the probabilities of the following) and p(G)=p(G=F)+p(G=M) (i.e. only boys and girls as classes), you have four possible realizations:

`FF|FM|MF|MM` where M=male, F=female

If you're trying to find the probability of *at least* one girl, you need to sum probabilities for the first three, but we can equivalently do 1-p(MM).

p(MM) is Binom(2, 0.5) or equivalently Bernoulli(0.5) + Bernoulli(0.5), which is `0.5*0.5 == 0.25`.

So, 1-that gives you the probability of ***at least*** one girl of 0.75.

Both being girls is given by the same Binom(2, 0.5) since the gender probabilities are equal, which we already know is 0.25.